# Gateway DX4850 Mainboard BIOS Update for Ivy Bridge

Tags: motherboard, bios, sandy-bridge, ivy-bridge

Does anyone know where I can find an updated BIOS that will handle Ivy Bridge CPU's for my otherwise fine DX4850-27eu?

I already have the latest BIOS that Gateway offers: version `P01-A3`, dated 2011/02/18 according to CPU-Z report (but which according to the Gateway website should be 2011/03/14 - I have verified they are the same update).

GPU-Z states the mainboard has `Southbridge H67 Rev. B3`, so I know the Ivy Bridge i7-3770 should work fine - ***IF*** I can upgrade the BIOS.

CPU-Z has this in its report,

```
BaseBoardInfo:
  - szBaseBoard_Manufacturer: Gateway
    szBaseBoard_Product: DX4850
    szBaseBoard_SerialNumber: ""
    szBaseBoard_Version: ""
```

*However*, I am wondering if this board was really made by someone else, and can be updated with a BIOS from somewhere other than Gateway.

Thank you.

Comment: The Intel H67 chipset doesn't Ivy Bridge processors

Comment: No there is not one, upgrade the motherboard to one that supports that processor.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've have read several places, e.g., http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/H67_Express.html and https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/h67-mobo-compatible-with-i7-3770-cpu.381942/, that H67 will support i7-3770, but only with a BIOS update. Do you think they might be misinformed? (Although, at this point, however, it is irrelevant, since I cannot get the BIOS update.) Thanks.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd Generation Core products were not compatible with one another.